# use maven to get the latest snapshot of a specific pom

Tags: svn, maven, build, artifact

In our environment we use Jenkins to build java artefacts.

We want a scriptbased buildsystem to automatically deploy the artifact and re-use the scripts we already have.

What I want to do is make the buildsystem extract the HEAD from svn and use Maven with some goal to get the latest artefact in the snapshot-repository as opposed to letting the buildsystem build the javaproject that already is deployd to the maven repo.

Comment: So you want your build server to checkout the code and then download the artifact w/o building the code? Huh?

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to create a new Jenkins job where you checkout your final artifact project (e.g. your application WAR) rather than the aggregator (i.e. multi-module) project you use to build all the libraries your application depends on. In this way Maven should assemble your application by pulling dependencies from your repository rather than by re-building them.